# What Could Explain A Solitary Mountain in a Grassland?

Tags: geography

That title is probably way too specific, but essentially I'm trying to develop my book's setting. Currently, my characters (a team of six adventurers) awaken as amnesiacs who were once human but now have been transformed into a motley menagerie, within a grassland. This hilly grassland has a road running through the center of it, and at one point, there lies a small mountain next to the road.

This mountain is rather important, as carved into its interior is a town named Rockhaven, where a plot-important SC (supporting character) awaits the team. What I don't know is what would cause a solitary mountain to form in the aforementioned biome-a grassland with rolling hills and plains-akin to the Kansan prairie. So, as you can see, my question is **What Could Explain A Solitary Mountain in a Grassland?**

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for a single mountain on a plain that is *like Kansas*, not how to add a mountain to the actual Kansas?

Comment: @Cadence: yes, that is correct.

Comment: You mean like that fictional and legendary solitary mountain in the middle of grassland called Kilimanjaro? 

Comment: Pluton. Igious intrusion. Sometime a volcano. Sometimes a "failed "volcano [link]https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igneous_intrusion

Comment: Someone drew too much of The One Power.

Comment: @Darren: Kilimanjaro is fictional?

Comment: @Alendyias no! It was sarcasm! My point was why ask on world building when there are several well-known examples OP could read up on, including the highest mountain in Africa.

Comment: @Darren: in my defense, I had no idea what forces could develop a solitary mountain, or where I could find them. Also, finding a mountain like the one I'm describing through Google is most likely beyond my researching powers.

Comment: @Darren I personally thought that the kilimandjaro was not all sad and alone ^^.

Comment: @Darren Kilimanjaro doesn't look solitary to me, seeing as it has other near by mountains, e.g. Mount Meru and the Pare Mountains. They are, admittedly, not immediately connected to Kilimanjaro, but are only something like 40 miles away. (Or a day's travel on foot in "medieval" conditions).

Comment: As an aside: you don't need to explain to the reader why the mountain is there. It's OK to let them draw their own conclusions, unless it's relevant to setting the scenery. eg, if the city is built in lava caves and lava tunnels, that'd change how the tunnels were described, even if you don't explicitly call them lava tunnels. But for the most part, just describing the shape of the hill and letting the geologists delight in the correctness should be fine.

Comment: @DewiMorgan: thanks! I know I can go overboard at times, so I will keep your advice in mind.

Comment: Most obviously, read about The Fist of God in the Ringworld series. Failing that, why not ignore the origins, and write the story? Rather, explain how "There's a mountain…" is not sufficient.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**I got your solitary mountain in a grassland right here!**

[image: devils tower]

https://mybestplace.com/en/article/devils-tower-the-legendary-rock-of-wyoming

Devil's Tower is the basalt core of an ancient igneous intrusion.  The surrounding softer stone has weathered away leaving the tower in a grassland.

Comment: +1. Nearby Bear Butte, SD, appears to be formed by a roughly similar process (volcanic), and looks more like a classic mountain shape. Probably did even more, before erosion. Both are reasonably close to the Black Hills, to be noted. Very cool places.

Comment: Ahh and you had the perfect picture of a road through the grassland from your article too! https://mybestplace.com/uploads/2021/04/Devils-Tower-Wyoming-4.jpg

Comment: I suddenly have a craving for mashed potatoes.

Comment: Devil's Tower is about 370 m tall, 250 m wide at the base and 100 m at the top. You could probably carve a village inside but not a town.

Comment: @pabouk - the suburbs could be outside the mountain.

Answer (score 54):

First thing that came to my mind was Mount Kilimanjaro:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Kilimanjaro

Highest solitary mountain in the world, surrounded by savanna grassland. Obviously, it's a volcano.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding! Your answer seems correct to me. Yet it would benefit from a bit of fleshing out, i think

Answer (score 25):

[It's the place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_Tjuta#Legends) where the great snake king, Wanambi, who resides at the top of the montain and only comes down to ground level in the dry season. His breath can turn a breeze into a hurricane, punishing those who committed evil deeds in the region.

[Kata Tjuta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_Tjuta)

> Kata Tjuṯa, (Pitjantjatjara: Kata Tjuṯa, lit. 'many heads'; Aboriginal pronunciation: [kɐtɐ cʊʈɐ]), also known as the Olgas, is a group of large, domed rock formations or bornhardts located about 360 km (220 mi) southwest of Alice Springs, in the southern part of the Northern Territory, central Australia. Uluṟu, also known as Ayers Rock, located 25 km (16 mi) to the east, and Kata Tjuṯa form the two major landmarks within the Uluṟu-Kata Tjuṯa National Park. The park is considered sacred to the Aboriginal people of Australia.

[image]

[Uluru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uluru#Age_and_origin)

> Uluru (/ˌuːləˈruː/; Pitjantjatjara: Uluṟu [ˈʊ.lʊ.ɻʊ]), also known as Ayers Rock (/ɛərz/ airz) and officially gazetted as Uluru / Ayers Rock, is a large sandstone formation in the southern part of the Northern Territory in Australia. It lies 335 km (208 mi) southwest of the nearest large town: Alice Springs.
>
> Uluru is sacred to the Pitjantjatjara, the Aboriginal people of the area, known as the Aṉangu. The area around the formation is home to an abundance of springs, waterholes, rock caves, and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a UNESCO World Heritage Site.

[image]

---

[List of inselbergs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inselbergs) around the world

Comment: Random fact: "Inselberg" is just German for "island mountain"

Comment: We really do have a word for everything

Answer (score 12):

All good answers so far in addition a [tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(rock_formation)) is also an option. Tors usually occur where igneous rocks, usually [granite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granite), that were deeply [intruded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igneous_intrusion) into softer rocks are brought to the surface by weathering. This usually creates quite high, steep, hills, usually of bare rock even in otherwise lush surroundings, in the middle of flat fertile bottom lands.

Answer (score 11):

Volcanos.  An example is the Sutter Buttes in California's Central Valley: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutter_Buttes  It's the eroded remains of a volcano, surrounded by flat land, and was almost certainly a larger mountain in the past.

A somewhat similar example is Mount Shasta.  Although some of the surroundings are mountainous (though much lower), some of the surrounding area, especially to the north is fairly flat grassland.  Shasta also has a set of legends which describe it as housing a city of advanced beings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Shasta  See also the Heinlein story "Lost Legacy".

Answer (score 10):

[image: Říp]

Another example is Říp hill in Czech Republic, remains of a tercer-age basalt intrusion or a volcano core. Even though it's related to other contemporary volcanos from a nearby mountain range, this hill stands alone in a gently rolling countryside. (img from [Wikipedia](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%98%C3%ADp))

Answer (score 6):

Ancient meteor strike. Large meteor craters have flat bottoms (your plain) and a large central peak (caused by the ground directly under the impact rebounding).

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_crater for some examples.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and I see your logic, but I'm not sure how well this would work. The sheer _size_ of the meteor would cause a major extinction event on impact, and the grassland itself is not entirely flat, it has hills and ridges. I do like the idea of Rockhaven being at the center of the area, though, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 5):

In ancient times, before the birth of America, even before the people we know as Native Americans populated the plains and rolling hills of the North American continent, there were a mysterious society of technologically advanced people known as the Mound Builders. To this day, people are still discovering their massive works hidden in plain sight, having been mistaken for centuries as naturally occurring hills and mountains. Some of these enormous man-made mountains were used as grave yards for the elite VIPs of their culture, others seem to have been designed to be sanctuaries in the event of sudden, catastrophic flooding, but most of these "mounds" were built for reasons that still evade explanation. Iowa, Kansas, Nebraska, Illinois, Missouri and Minnesota were favored by these people for mountain building, as the miles upon miles of flat land emphasized their work's looming presence on the landscape.

Comment: I have to take issue with your statement about [Mound Builders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mound_Builders) being before Native Americans. While there are old mounds, the culture of creating mounds in North America was somewhat continuous, and lasted up until European contact. Saying that they were built "before the people we know as Native Americans" is akin to saying the Colosseum was built "before the people we know as Italians".

Comment: I actually read recently or was it youtube, about mountains created by cement and mining industries. So ancient technocrat civilization is a viable option.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is a town in the interior of the mountain, perhaps the "mountan" is acutally a gigantic building built to contain a totally self enclosed habitat, including the town, reached by a few airlocks leading to the outside world.

And maybe the outside of the building has slowly weathered and assumed a more rugged and natural shape, although it still looks very artifical compared to most real mountains.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give an alternative to (dead) volcanoes or volcanic intrusions:

**[Salt tectonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_tectonics)**

A salt dome may push a solitary rock or hill upwards, examples are the [Segeberger Kalkberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segeberger_Kalkberg) in Bad Segeberg, Germany, or the off-shore island [Heligoland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heligoland) (imagine a lower sea level to place it in a grass plain).

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for enlightening me! I will have to do further research on this.